# Loopback remote method - getting empty request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I am having this weird issue in loopback, when hitting a custom remote method the body is returned as undefined. I have worked with loopback before but never ever encountered this issue,I am not sure what i am missing here. can someone please help.

```
Users.greet = function(msg, cb) {
console.log(msg)
cb(null, 'Greetings... ' + msg);
}

Users.remoteMethod('greet', {
    accepts: {arg: 'msg', type: 'json', http: { source: 'req' }},
    returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'string'}
});
```

when I remove the http flag in accepts it returns undefined.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I just tested removing the `http: { source: 'req' }` from the accepts property and now it is working. If you need to receive a param by the URL change the http source to `http: { source: 'path' }`

Comment: It should have worked like that but dont know why its not. May be something with my node version i guess. anyways thanks :)